# Select plain text in between tags

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm trying to select some text between 2 html tags. It should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to figure it out.

HTML:

```
<article>
    width
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span> 
    80%
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
</article>
```

So I'm trying to select the word `Width` and the value, `80%` and store each in a different element.
The end result would be something like:

```
<article>
    <span class="Property">width</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">:</span>
    <span class="Value"> 80%</span>
    <span class="Punctuation">;</span>
</article>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

---

--- EDIT ---

I've already marked a reply as the right answer but is there any way to make it cleaner?

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: wrap the words in a div element and use text() method in jquery

Comment: I'm trying to do wrap the plain text from the article in <span> elements. .text() doesnt work because it selects BOTH "width" and "80%". I need to select them seperately.

Look at my desired outcome. "width" and "80%" are both <span elements but have different classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('article').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).first().wrap('<span class="Property" />');

$('article').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).last().wrap('<span class="value" />');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bMWB/)**

Comment: Nice answer +1 I was working on a much longer example. (http://jsfiddle.net/6her5/1/) but doesn't come close to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery .text() - http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
$('.Punctuation').text();
$('.Value').text();
```

Comment: This selects all the text in the Punctuation span. The text Im trying to select isnt in the span but in the parent element.